# Unity - Add Material To Game Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm am trying to create a script that continuously generates objects and attaches a script to all the generated objects. I want the attached script to after 3 seconds, change the material on the object and add a box collider. My problem is with the material. Since the object was randomly generated, I don't know how to set the material variable. This is my Spawner:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
    //Variables
    public float x_max;
    public float x_min;
    public float y_max;
    public float y_min;
    private float Size;
    public float s_max;
    public float s_min;
    public float w_max;
    public float w_min;
    private float ProceduralCacheSize;
    private GameObject sphere;
    private float waitTime = 5f;
    private int fix;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Spawn ();
        Spawn ();
        Spawn ();
        StartCoroutine("MyCoroutine");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void Spawn(){
            Size = Random.Range (s_min, s_max);
            sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            sphere.transform.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (x_min, x_max), Random.Range (y_min, y_max), 0);
            sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (Size, Size, Size);
            var fbs = sphere.AddComponent<Astroid> ();
        }

    IEnumerator MyCoroutine(){
        StartCoroutine("Change");
        waitTime = Random.Range (w_min, w_max);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        StartCoroutine("MyCoroutine");
        StartCoroutine("Change");
        Spawn ();
    }
}
```

And this is the script that gets attached:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Astroid : MonoBehaviour {
    //I need to be able to set this variable to a material
    public Material mat;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        this.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine("Change");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    IEnumerator Change(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
        this.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().enabled = true;
        this.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = mat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a public static int like this.
Your Spawner:

```css
public Material mat;
public static Material mat2;
void Start(){
mat2 = mat;
}
```

And in your astroid script:

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Astroid : MonoBehaviour {
 //I need to be able to set this variable to a material
 //public Material mat;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  this.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().enabled = false;
  StartCoroutine("Change");
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  
 }
 IEnumerator Change(){
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
  this.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().enabled = true;
  this.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Spawner.mat2;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just load it from resources

mat = Resources.Load("myMaterial.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;

Comment: This answer is incorrect. According to [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), extensions must be omitted.